# iOS Textview Tap issue with tableview celltap

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I want to open textview link into the browser.
It working fine for me. using this code.

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
textView.editable = NO;
```

But I want cell tap if user tap on textview other then link.
But currently when user tap on textview other then link cell tap is not working.

I am not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a UITapGestureRecognizer on the textView like
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];       [textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoDetailVc)];

Answer (score -1):

You have to make CustomCell for it, put the UITextView in custom cell and its `viewDidLoad` method set

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
textView.editable = NO;
```